# Plot cumulative line with Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have data set with two weekly series.Below you can see code for data and also code for plot with plotly.

```
# Code
library(plotly)
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

ARTEFICIAL_DATA<-data.frame(structure(list(week = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
                                                    13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18), `2019 Series_1` = c(1286, 838, 1537, 
                                                                                                 880, 1090, 1277, 1104, 622, 405, 729, 863, 716, 648, 1042, 765, 
                                                                                                 913, 684, 615), `2020 Series_1` = c(559, 456, 1348, 1083, 930, 
                                                                                                                                     1068, 1024, 691, 747, 635, 740, 665, 465, 442, 437, 764, 378, 
                                                                                                                                     392)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                                     )))


WEEKLY_TOTAL_REVENUE_PLOTLY<-ARTEFICIAL_DATA%>%
  select(week,`2019 Series_1`,`2020 Series_1`)

dat <-as.data.table(WEEKLY_TOTAL_REVENUE_PLOTLY)
colnames(dat) <- c('week', 'series1', 'series2')

fig <- plot_ly(dat, x = ~week, y = ~series2, name = "2019", type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
               line = list(dash = "dash")) 
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~series1, name = "2020", line = list(dash = "solid"))%>% 
  layout(
    xaxis = list(title = 'week'), 
    yaxis = list(title = 'Dollars')
  )

fig
```

So this line of code produce graph with plotly like example below.

[image]

But my intention is to have cummulative line like example below.

[image]

So can anybody help me how to plot like example above with Plotly ?

Comment: Can you add columns with cumulative sum, and use them in your plot? For example, `dat$cum_series1 <- cumsum(dat$series1)`, and something similar for `series2` and then use `cum_series1` and `cum_series2` in `plot_ly` and `add_trace`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to transform the data to user cumulative sum:

```
dat <- dat %>% mutate(series1 = cumsum(series1),series2 = cumsum(series2))

fig <- plot_ly(dat, x = ~week, y = ~series2, name = "2019", type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
               line = list(dash = "dash")) 
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~series1, name = "2020", line = list(dash = "solid"))%>% 
  layout(
    xaxis = list(title = 'week'), 
    yaxis = list(title = 'Dollars')
  )

fig
```

[image]